# fitsSystemWindows breaks MotionLayout transition

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I have a MotionLayout transition bound to ViewPager.

```
private val pageChangedListener = object : SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
        motionLayout.progress = (position + positionOffset) / (pager.adapter!!.count - 1)
    }
}
```

Everything works great, except the fitsSystemWindows, which, when added to the MotionLayout, breaks the animation. The whole layout jumps at the beginning of animation and at the end. It looks like the padding is added twice when the motionLayout is not exactly 0 or 1. I've prepared two videos with fitsSystemWindows set to true and false to better visualise the issue.

Please note that the layout on the videos is simplified, the transition is obviously much more complicated, but this is enough to see the difference. Also, I'm using `constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3`.

`fitsSystemWindows="true" ->` https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKYLq.jpg - animation jumping at the start and end.

`fitsSystemWindows="false" ->` https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms1xi.jpg - no jumping, but the bottom button doesn't fit system window obviously.

**Any ideas how to fix the transition?**

---

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

...

<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="..."
        android:textSize="52sp" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
        style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="28dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
        android:letterSpacing=".1"
        android:text="..."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

MotionScene xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:duration="250"
    motion:interpolator="linear">

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/titleTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/timerLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/titleTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:scaleX="0.6"
            android:scaleY="0.6"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:alpha="0.5" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/timerLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="430dp"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

</Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

Comment: Could you add the code from your layouts?

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk I just did, thanks for your interest.

Comment: Seems like a bug, I don't think MotionLayout takes status bar height into account during the animation, and only applies it in the before and after states. (It is still in Alpha, after all) I suggest filing an issue with google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Comment: Did u solve it? I have same problem

Comment: Nope, I didn't unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I have solved it by adding `MotionLayout.TransitionListener` to motion layout. You can try it for your case.

```
motion_layout.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {

    /** Called when a drawer is about to start a transition*/
    override fun onTransitionStarted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int) { }

    /** Called when a drawer's position changes*/
    override fun onTransitionChange(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int, progress: Float) { }

    /** Called when a drawer has settled completely a state*/
    override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
        motionLayout?.let {
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(it) { _, insets ->
                image.setMarginTop(insets.systemWindowInsetTop)
                insets
            }
        }
    }

    /** Call when a trigger is fired*/
    override fun onTransitionTrigger(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, triggerId: Int, positive: Boolean, progress: Float) { }
})
```